# Problema com caracteres especiais laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estou começando a aprender sobre o Laravel 5 e estou com um problema, todo texto que escrevo com caracteres especiais é convertido para '�'.

Já tentei todo tipo de configuração no charset desde ISO-8859-1 até UTF-8.

Tem alguma forma de configurar isso no laravel para não ter que escrever tudo com &; ?

Comment: Parece ser um erro no seu editor e não no Laravel. Certifique-se de que a header `Content-Type` possui `charset=UTF8`

Comment: No sei editor de texto, verifique a codificação do ficheiro. Por exemplo, no notepadd++ tem que ter algo deste género: Codificação -> Codificar em UTF-8 sem BOD

Answer (score 1):

Não cheguei a utilizar o Laravel, mas a maioria dos frameworks possuem uma configuração de charset (vale lembrar também que o recomendável é o seu banco estar no mesmo charset).

[Este link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399160/laravel-5-charset-not-working-correctly-on-the-views-but-it-working-well-when-i) talvez possa resolver o seu problema

Comment: Tentei essa solução mas aparentemente é algum tipo de erro no laravel que acontece apos o parse na view... Não obtive exito :/

Comment: Eu já tive um problema parecido pois o charset do arquivo no sublime estava diferente, apenas mudei para utf-8 e voltou a funcionar, talvez seja uma solução.

Comment: tentei isso tbm mas o charset do sublime ja esta utf-8 :/

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o problema está no encode do Blade(Sistema de Template do Laravel), vai no arquivo `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` e deixa o método `boot` dessa forma =

```
public function boot()  
{  
    parent::boot();  
    \Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi incluindo a tag

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

no meu head do master page do blade.

Comment: Acredito que você vez outra coisa para isso. Como a inclusão de uma fonte pode resolver esse problema?

Comment: Eu removi o metacharset UTF-8 e inclui a fonte. Mas obrigado pelo voto negativo.